# Setting a Select control in a form with Mechanize using Python

Tags: python, forms, controls, mechanize

I'm trying to use mechanize to select a form

```
browser.select_form('frmChangeLanguage')
```

.. got that.

But I'm struggling with changing a drop down box within the form and then submitting the form with the new value. The control looks like this:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<select id="controlID" class="select" name="selectLang">
<option value='4' selected>en</option>
<option value='1' >fr</option>
<option value='2' >hk</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit"/></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I'm currently doing:

```
control = browser.form.controls[0]
control._value = 1    
browser.submit(name='button')
```

but this doesn't seem to be working. Any ideas?
I'm using Python 2.7 with Mechanize installed on Windows.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/forms.html), the following should work:

```
form["selectLang"] = ["1"]
mechanize.urlopen(form.click())
```

Comment: Your answer would have been more useful, if you showed where variable `form` was defined.